# Why does it show #REF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP($C3,INDIRECT(“‘“&&I$4&”’!C2:D22”),4,0)
```

I got moving or deleting cells caused an invalid cell reference Or function is returning reference error.

Have checked everywhere I could and don't know how to clear it.

I was expecting it to bring a drop down of all the months and what’s in the cell of the selected column.

Comment: That is probably because of the tilted speech marks you need to use the straight one. `=VLOOKUP($C3,INDIRECT("'"&&I$4&"'!C2:D22"),4,0)` it should be this one `"` & `'`

Comment: Because you have incorrect quotes in there. It should be `"` and `'` and not `“`/`”` and `‘`/`’`. My assumption is that at some point you had written that code in MS Word. The morale of the story is to never use MS Word for programming, it's not what's it's for. Use a proper code editor or for something small you can simply use Windows' notepad tool.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you straighten out the quotes and remove the extra &, you still get the #REF! error. This is caused by the fact that the vlookup is trying to return a result from column 4, but there are only two columns in the range. So either change the 4 to 2, or change the range.

```
=VLOOKUP($C3,INDIRECT("'"&I$4&"'!C2:D22"),2,0)
```

or

```
VLOOKUP($C3,INDIRECT("'"&I$4&"'!C2:F22"),4,0)
```

Assumes there is a valid sheet name in I4.

Comment: Thanks! - maybe more of a comment than an answer but I prefer to answer rather than comment.

Comment: Sir, I agree, thought it was a typo so didnt posted as an answer, but when you posted realized that there is one more issue.